# 'auto *const' has incompatible initializer of type std::_Array_iterator<char, 48>

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, iterator, stdarray

I am trying to compile this code with *clang 11.0.1*, [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), for the PS4 platform. The `some_array` is `std::array` which is initialized as `std::array<char, 48> some_array{{}};`

```
auto* const characters = std::remove(some_array.begin(),
                        some_array.begin() + length, filtered_character);
```

and I get the following error

```
'auto *const' has incompatible initializer of type std::_Array_iterator<char, 48>
```

I am not sure if I need to suppress the warning using *cmake* or something to do with the logic.

Comment: Yes. I'm compiling using ps4 sdk platform

Comment: Ok. a C++14 tag on your question would be good too. You can only use 5 tags though so it'll be hard to replace one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) returns the **[forward iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator), not a pointer**.

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
ForwardIt remove( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );
^^^^^^^^^^
```

In your case, it is of type

```
std::array<char, 48>::iterator
```

Therefore, you do not need to add the `auto*`, rather let the compiler deduce the type for you. So you need simply `auto` :

```
auto characters = std::remove(some_array.begin()
    , some_array.begin() + length
    , filtered_character);
```

In order to verify the type. [see here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hedj6sK3e)

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same_v

auto characters = std::remove(some_array.begin()
    , some_array.begin() + length
    , filtered_character);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(characters), std::array<char, 48>::iterator>
    , "Are not same!");
```

---

As a side note, the algorithm `std::remove` will not actually remove any elements, but instead only move them to the end of the sequence,  in such a way that, all "removed" elements fall behind a certain boundary in your range.

If your intention was to erase the elements, you should think of containers such as [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), etc with [erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) or simply [`std::erase`(Since C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions_2#Uniform_container_erasure). [It is not possible with `std::array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57356480/erase-element-from-std-array)

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary that the iterator is defined as a pointer for the class template `std::array`. **It is implementation defined** (though some C++ libraries can indeed implement the iterator as a pointer).

And this error message

```
'auto *const' has incompatible initializer of type std::_Array_iterator<char, 48>
```

means that really in the used compiler and its libraries the iterator is not a pointer.

So use

```
auto characters = std::remove(some_array.begin(),
                  some_array.begin() + length, filtered_character);
```

Comment: That worked like charm. Thank you so much

Comment: "_It is not necessary that the iterator is defined as a pointer_" - No, but it's defined as a literal type since C++17, so a pointer is a pretty good bet, starting with C++17 that is.