# Segmentation fault when remove duplicate value in pointer array

Tags: c++

When debugging, I found that segmentation fault caused after copy from temp array (b) to original array (a), I don't know how to solve this, can you guys help me on that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    int *a = new int[n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    cout << "\nNumber to remove: ";
    int k;
    cin >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        while (a[i] == k && i < n - 1)
        {
            int *b = new int[n]{0};
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                b[j] = a[j];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                b[j - 1] = a[j];

            a = NULL;
            delete a;
            n--;
            int *a = new int[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                a[j] = b[j];
        }
    }

    cout << "Result: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: `int *a = new int[n];` inside the loop must be `a = ...`. You are declaring a _new_ `a`, that is unelated to the `a` from outside the loop. (The first `a`, from outside the loop, will be `NULL` at the end of the loop and never change again.

Comment: `a = NULL; delete a;`  - how do you expect that to work?

Comment: TBH this would be so much more readable with `std::vector`.

Comment: @Chí Bằng Hoàng The reason of the error is the awful and too complicated code. To remove a value from an array there is no any need to allocate dynamically an auxiliary array each time then the target value is removed.

Comment: @MSalters It works very well. The problem is that there is a memory leak.:)

Comment: @Chí Bằng Hoàng The program does not make a sense.

Comment: Well, I learned that I need to copy original array when delete it, may be I'm wrong. So what is the better solution?

Comment: @ChíBằngHoàng *what is the better solution?* -- `auto iter = std::remove(a, a + n, k);` and then `iter` points to the end of the valid values in the array.  You don't need all of this convoluted code to remove a value from an array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for your suggest, but I haven't learn that yet

Comment: @ChíBằngHoàng: If you're doing memory management yourself, then yes, you should delete the original array `a`. The problem is that you first set `a=NULL` so the next line is effectively `delete NULL`. You don't delete the `new int[n]`. BTW, if you really, really must use `new[]`, then it should also be `delete[]`. It only "works"  now because `delete NULL`  and `delete[] NULL`  both do nothing. But just use `vector`, really.

Comment: My advice (if you can't use a std::vector<int>) is don't reallocate a smaller array each time. You are doing way too much allocation. You also should remove the `b` dynamic array completly.

Comment: @ChíBằngHoàng *but I haven't learn that yet* -- And most people asking a question on stackoverflow didn't learn yet what they are given as an answer or as a comment.  Wouldn't now be the best time to learn?  Every other profession works this way, where you are being taught new and better things, so why not programming?

Comment: This question should help you remove an item from an array without needing to allocate a second array: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879603/remove-an-array-element-and-shift-the-remaining-ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879603/remove-an-array-element-and-shift-the-remaining-ones)

Comment: Thank y'all for the answer, I will take a look into them :||

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this implementation lies here:

```
a = NULL;
delete a;
```

When you use the `delete` keyword you are telling the compiler to free the memory allocated by a `new` keyword, in this case you have `a` which is a pointer to the memory allocated by `int *a = new int[n];`. `a` at this point would probably be a 32bit address for example `0xbfebd5c0`, i said probably because it depends on the architecture of the machine, however... after that you are setting `a` to NULL resulting in `a` being `0x0`, at the next `while` condition check `a` is `NULL` and accessing `0x0 + i` is not possible due to safety reasons imposed by the OS (no one gave you access to this location). The solution to your specific problem would be removing `a = NULL;` and `delete a;` as both these operations interfere with the `while` condition check.

I would suggest to take another approach at solving this problem since you really don't need to do this many dynamic allocations.

Comment: While the answer to remove `a = NULL;` is correct, the explanation isn't. Deleting a null-pointer is perfectly fine. But you are correct that deleting an arbitray address would cause an error. Null-pointers are special in that regard.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are totally right, the actual reason is that he is looping on a condition which depends on `a` hence accessing some displaced location in respect to 0x0, which he isn't allowed to do. Thanks @churill